# Javascript - Problem with modal close on click outside

Tags: javascript, html

i've been trying to close a modal when clicking outside using Vainilla JS but i dont know how to close in that way this modal. My modal has a form to send information to a DB with a send button. Please dont tell me a solution with JQuery.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" id="modal_box" style="display:block; position:absolute;">


        <div class="modal-content">


            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    <strong id="spnSummTitle">
                        <center>
                             Title Modal
                        </center>
                    </strong>
                </h3>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-body" style="height:350px;">
                <div style="display:block" >
                    
                 //Information to send

                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btn_send" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div>


        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your current code that does not work and we will try to help you

Comment: Looks like homework to me :)

Comment: Can you please post your question with snippet and js code in it?